# Difference in site apperance when viewed in firefox and chrome

Tags: css

open the following URL in chrome
[www.nextag.com/camera/stores-html](http://www.nextag.com/camera/stores-html)
and refresh the page

Notice the location of the help icon next to ZIP code on top right corner..it is misaligned
Now open the same in firefox.. it is properly aligned..

CSS code for this is as follows:

```
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
border: 1px solid #C2CCCC;
border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
color: #C2CCCC;
display: block;
float: right;
font-weight: bold;
height: 13px;
margin-left: 4px;
text-align: center;
width: 12px;
padding-right: 1px;
```

to make it work in firefox.. i added the following 3 ATTRIBUTES:

```
position: relative;
top: -15px;
left: 18px;
```

then it started working fine in chrome, but now it got misaligned in firefox.. what do i do??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a SPAN inside A. Simply disable the "float: right" property and add "display: inline"

```
.rb span.zip-info {
    dispay: inline;
    float: none;
}
```

Comment: i did what you said and in addition to it i removed the padding-right and added padding: 0px 3px attribut.. everything was solved but the icons size was reduced somehow compared to the what it should be!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the "*position: absolute*" attribute instead of "*position: relative*"?

Seems like Firefox has an invisible padding or margin that places the element at the top right of the text space. Chrome is placing the element at the top right of the fieldset element outside of the flow of text.

You can do one thing add a div wrapper and then absolutely position the element in the top right of the wrapper.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes, i tried it with absolute, relative, static etc.
None of them worked.
static was working fine in firefox, but then it went wrong in chrome :/

Answer (score 1):

Add property `float:left`

```
.rb #zipTxt a {
color: #2283AB;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
float: left;
}
```